# Check if User is Logged into App Store? Objc iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to check if the users have a subscription bought it by In-App Purchase. 
The problem is that my API needs to know which user already bought a subscription in order to unlock the Plus content. For an error in the purchase process we couldn't get the receipt of several users.

We know that using Restore Purchase we can get the order receipt but those users don't know that they need to restore it, so in this case we can call restore purchases automatically when the user enter in the dashboard.

The problem now is if the user don't have an apple store account associated in the device, the IAP library show a modal telling to the users that need to sign  in the itunes & apple store, and the idea is avoid show that message to the user that never has signed in the app store.

There is a way to verify if the user is logged into app store?

Comment: No. This is not possible.

Comment: You can attempt to refresh the receipt when your app starts, but that will result in an App Store login prompt if they aren't logged in.  I suggest always having a restore button in your app; that way if you do have a user who contacts your support regarding missing IAPs, you can direct them to the restore button.  Users may even find the button themselves, avoiding a support incident

Comment: No, with out proper apple id and password enter In-App Purchase is not possbile

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys. I couldn't do it as I wanted, now I have the restore purchase manually.